# How to condition a private sub macro based on a public one in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I want to only run a private sub after a public sub macro is executed in VBA. I want data to be entered into a spreadsheet, the public macro is run, and following the run of the public macro, I want to lock the cells that were used in the macro. Currently, I have a private sub that locks the cell following data entry, I want it to lock the cell following execution of the public macro using the data entered. The sheet and workbook are both password protected and previous entries are locked

```
`Some pseudocode for reference:
Private Sub
ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="123"
If Call Public Sub Macro Then
Target.Locked= True
End if
ActiveSheet.Protect Passwor:="123"
End Sub`


`Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="123"
Target.Locked = True
ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="123"
End Sub`
```

I have this updated code now:

```
' Define a global flag variable
Public flagMacroExecuted As Boolean

Sub PublicMacro()
    ' Set the flag variable to indicate that the macro has been executed
    flagMacroExecuted
    flagMacroExecuted = True

    ' Call the private sub if the macro has been executed
    If flagMacroExecuted Then
        PrivateMacro Selection
    End If

    
End Sub

Private Sub PrivateMacro(ByVal Target As Range)
    ' Lock the column with data entered
    Dim columnRange As Range
    Set columnRange = Target.EntireColumn
    columnRange.Locked = True
    
    ' Protect the worksheet
    ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="123"
End Sub
```

Now the problem is, I am getting Ambiguous Error for the PublicMacro that I am calling because I have a macro with the same name thats actually doing what the PublicMacro is meant to do. How can I facilitate this by flagging when this macro is used

Comment: I don't understand...  "I am getting Ambiguous Error for the PublicMacro that I am calling..." In your code i can't see call to PublicMacro. I have not understood which objects have the same name, but why should they have the same name? Can't you give them different names?

Answer (score 0):

Try calling both subs from `Worksheet_Change`, and lock the cells where appropriate (after the public sub?). Some variation of the pseudo code below should ensure the subs are called in your desired order.

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Call PublicSub

    ' Lock changed cells here?
    
    Call PrivateSub
    
End Sub
```